# Нужна ли здесь return?

Tags: javascript

Написал код, который каждые 2 секунды вставляет html элемент поверх предыдущего.

Затем спрашивает остановить ли цикл.

Чувствую, что здесь в коде не хватает **return**, но где именно нужно разместить **return**?

```js
let timer = setTimeout(function fun(){
main.innerHTML += main.innerHTML;
timer = setTimeout(fun, 2000);

let a = confirm('Остановить цикл?');
if(a == true){
clearTimeout(timer);    
alert('Цикл остановлен');   
} 
},1000)
```

```css
#main{
background: orange; 
}

#home {
font-size: 2vmax;   
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="home">
Опа
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: что должен возвращать этот return и куда?

Comment: Зачем? Чтобы был return в коде?)

Comment: Так умные люди на этом форуме сказали, что return всегда нужен.

Comment: Значит они не умные) либо вы не так поняли. Есть случаи когда "return" не нужен.

Comment: В моём случае return не нужен?

Comment: Смотря что ожидается. Если вначале печать - потом вопрос - не нужен. Если вначале вопрос - потом печать - вроде тоже. Так что не до конца ясно какая у вас вообще логика выполнения в голове

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return нужно поставить перед вызовом alert, а верхнее содержимое функции надо перенести вниз.
JS:

```
let timer = setTimeout(function fun(){
  let a = confirm('Остановить цикл?');
  if(a === true){
    clearTimeout(timer);    
    return alert('Цикл остановлен');   
  } 
  main.innerHTML += main.innerHTML;
  timer = setTimeout(fun, 2000);
},1000)
```

CSS:

```
#main{
background: orange; 
}

#home {
font-size: 2vmax;   
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="home">
Опа
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, проблема в том, что программа вставляет лишние элементы, даже когда нажимаешь "остановить цикл". Если так, то я прав

Comment: Да, есть такой баг) А где timer = setTimeout(fun, 2000); и clearTimeout(timer); тама return не нужны?

Comment: @Новичок, когда программа выполняет return, она выходит из функции. Это даже не баг, это так и задумывалось изначально. Так что там это не понадобится, так как эти строчки я перенес вниз функции.

Comment: Грубо говоря это работает так: нижние строки выполняются, а когда вы решаете остановить цикл, выполняется конструкция if, в которой находится return. Если же поставить return вниз, то функция выполнится один раз и больше новые элементы не выведутся.

Comment: Очень помогли, спс

Answer (score -1):

Вначале печать, потом вопрос (обратите внимание, тут `setInterval`, а не `setTimeout`)

```js
let i = 0;

let timer = setInterval(function fun() {
  main.innerHTML = i++;
 
  let a = confirm('Остановить цикл?');
  
  if (a == true) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    alert('Цикл остановлен');
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
#main {
  background: orange;
}

#home {
  font-size: 2vmax;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="home">
    Опа
  </div>
</div>
```

Вначале вопрос, потом печать:

```js
let i = 0;

let timer = setInterval(function fun() {  
  let a = confirm('Остановить цикл?');
  
  if (a == true) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    alert('Цикл остановлен');
  } else {
     main.innerHTML = i++;
  }  
}, 1000)
```

```css
#main {
  background: orange;
}

#home {
  font-size: 2vmax;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="home">
    Опа
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Никаких `return` нету ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Это совсем другое, код должен создавать новые блоки верстки, а не менять контент одного существующего

Comment: Согласен, это другой код, но по принципу действия чем-то аналогичен =)

Comment: @Listopad02 здесь специально упрощено, чтобы показать, что можно обойтись без всяких rerurn. Автор и сам может добавить свой код в нужное ему место

Comment: @Новичок код отличается только тем, что я вывожу в консоль, для наглядности. В целом это можно обратно заменить на вставку html. Главное чтобы вы поняли, что тут никаких return не обязательно писать

Comment: А зачем тогда нужен return, если его можно и не писать?
Для чего придумали return?

Comment: @Новичок как я уже писал вам под вопросом....цитирую себя: Есть случаи когда "return" не нужен.....то есть НЕ ВСЕГДА не нужен, а ИНОГДА............. для return.... ну вы из функции как вернёте значение без return?))

Comment: А какую роль выполняет return? Что она делает?

Comment: @Новичок вам пожалуй стоит задать этот вопрос на стаке, т.к. обсуждать в комментариях эту тему немного не то)

Comment: Правильно, а то админ наругает =)